# Error on dynamic column headers with mySQL

Tags: mysql

This question in regarding mySQL.
I am reading data from an .csv file that looks like this

original table

```
------------------------------------
Id      2018M01   2018M02  2018M03
------------------------------------
EMEA     3        1          4
ASPAC    4        5          4
ASPAC    1        2          1
```

expected result

```
---------------------
ID        Month     Qty
---------------------
EMEA      2018M01    3
EMEA      2018M02    1
EMEA      2018M03    4
ASPAC     2018M01    4
.......
```

The months column header are dynamic, that is each month there will be new months and old months will be removed. However the total number of columns will remain the same.

Hence whenever the month columns headers change I would like the SQL code to dynamically read and provide correct results without me having to manually change several parts of the code.

I have written the following code; Code is to unpivot the month columns. However I tested the code by manually making changes to the .csv file headers by changing 2018M03 to 2018M04, and rerunning the SQL code, but it still seems to print the old data . What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you. I am fairly new to SQL.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book;

CREATE TABLE book (
    ID VARCHARACTER(10),
    2018M01 decimal(4,2),
    2018M02 decimal(4,2),
    2018M03 decimal(4,2)
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/blytonpereira/Desktop/Book1.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE book 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;

DESCRIBE book;

SELECT ID, '2018M01' AS month, 2018M01 AS qty from book
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, '2018M02' AS month, 2018M02 AS qty from book
UNION ALL 
SELECT ID, '2018M03' AS month, 2018M03 AS qty from book;

SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'select ID, ''',
      c.column_name,
      ''' AS month, ',
      c.column_name,
   ' as qty 
      from book
      where ',
      c.column_name,
      ' > 0'
    ) SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
  ) INTO @sql
FROM information_schema.columns c
where c.table_name = 'book'
  and c.column_name not in ('id')
order by c.ordinal_position;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('select id, month, qty
           from
           (', @sql, ') x  order by id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** Updated answer: 
This solution is dynamic, whatever columns you have in table, it will populate them and extract information in required format. For sure columns have to have something in common, like they're all begins with "2018", you can change that as needed in Query.

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
      'SELECT id, ''', COLUMN_NAME, ''' as month, ', COLUMN_NAME, ' as QTY FROM t1 ') SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
FROM
  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE
  `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE '2018%'
INTO @sql;

SET @query = CONCAT('select id, month, QTY from (' , @sql , ') x order by id;');


SELECT @query;

 PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
 EXECUTE stmt;
```

**Note: the query has 2 outputs, first is the prepared concatenated query string (just to know what it looks like before run), and the other is the actual data. If you want only actual data you can comment (SELECT @query;) or remove it.

Comment: however this method will work but it will not make it dynamic. The remaining part of my code is supposed to achieve the dynamic nature of changing data but does not seem to be working. Can you pls identify why is it so ?

Comment: your method works fine, but for example the header in my data set is changed from 2018M03 to 2018M04, the data is reading is reading correctly in SQL, but the column header is still printing 2018M03. Is there any way to automatically update the header to the new header name ?

Comment: for me It is still not working. I feel I am doing something wrong. I am running the code in the following steps:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book;

CREATE TABLE book (
    ID VARCHARACTER(10),
    2018M01 decimal(4,2),
    2018M02 decimal(4,2),
    2018M03 decimal(4,2)
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/blytonpereira/Desktop/Book1.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE book 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;

AND then running your part of the code.

Comment: I created table exactly like your data, (image attached ), make sure you have the same format on your table after import and so, and after that run the query and tell me what is the result. image link :https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/1/1/986d8f47348b93be8a36b1180ccbac18-full.jpg

Comment: ok thank you it now seems to be working. Please see attached image for code and result https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/1/1/4011360a5e73d41888847462bdd3e6b1-full.png
In a normal use case I will need to read another similar .csv file with a different range of month e..g 2018M02 2018M03 2018M04....in this case which parts of the code do I need to write again  ? I am assuming the LOAD data part with a new table name and ?